# Scrapy does not enable my FilePipeline

Tags: python, file, download, scrapy, pipeline

This is my settings.py:

```
from scrapy.log import INFO


BOT_NAME = 'images'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['images.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'images.spiders'
LOG_LEVEL = INFO

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    "images.pipelines.WritePipeline": 800
}

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.5
```

This is my pipelines.py:

```
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline


class WritePipeline(FilesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for url in item["file_urls"]:
            yield Request(url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        return item
```

It is very standard, normal stuff. And yet this is a line of my log:

```
2015-06-25 18:16:41 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
```

So the pipeline is not enabled. What am I doing wrong here? I've used Scrapy a few times now, and I'm fairly positive the spider is fine. The item is just a normal item with `file_urls` and `files`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whoops, I forgot to add a `FILES_STORE` in the settings. Look [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#enabling-your-media-pipeline) for an explanation.

Relevant quote:

> Then, configure the target storage setting to a valid value that will be used for storing the downloaded images. Otherwise the pipeline will remain disabled, even if you include it in the ITEM_PIPELINES setting.

Comment: It worked! It is strange that scrapy does not raise an exception or a warning that a setting is missing, and simply skips the FilePipeline implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about `FilesPipeline`, but for every pipeline you need to implement the `process_item(self, item, spider)` method.

Comment: I added a process_item() and it was still disabled. Plus the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html) doesn't seem to require it.